# Doctrine wants to create tables, which are already existing by schema update

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-3.2

I have executed

bin/console d:s:u --force

Then the schema was created successfully. However, if I execute this command again, Symfony wants to re-create the schema. How can this be?

See full command line output:

```
$ bin/console d:s:u --force
Updating database schema...
Database schema updated successfully!
"7" queries were executed
$ bin/console d:s:u --force
Updating database schema...

[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableExistsException]                        
An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE message (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, user_id INT DEFAULT NULL, subject VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, text VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_B6BD307FA76ED395 (user_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'message' already exists                                              

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                   
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'message' already exists 

[PDOException]                                                        
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'message' already exists
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this config option, which caused the trouble:

> schema_filter: "/user_field_data/"